# Handling @Transactional rollbackFor with @Where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

This is my `Entity`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
@Where(clause = "count >= 0")
public class Example {
  @Column(name="count")
  private Integer count;

  //some code
}
```

This is my `DML` operation:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void updateService {
    update();
}

void update(){
    // findOne(Id) - if null throw Exception
    // --count & save()                        //line 8
    // findOne(Id) if null throw Exception     //line 9
    // --count & save()


    // if something fails 
    throw new Exception("Exception thown.");
}
```

Suppose initially value of `count` is `0` for `Id` in db. `line 9` will also return a records since `line 8` has not been commited yet. There is no `exception` `thrown`. It will not `rollback` and update the db, which should not happen. Can anyone help, If any `hibernate`/`JPA` solution exists for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be prevented by applying constraint to `count` `column`:

```
@Column(name = "count")
@Min(0)
private Integer count;
```

Now `save()` will `throw` [`org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionSystemException.html).